# Using pipe formula to pull correct value from a different data frame

Tags: r, database, tidyverse, dplyr

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get a data value out of a data frame, Inflation.

Within the code below, I want to multiply a value in my data frame iData by an inflation value. This depends on the data year for that value, and the year of the coefficient I'm using, but I can't figure out the best way to get the code to work.

```
    Inflation <- structure(list(ID = 2:211, Code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "GBP", class = "factor"), 
    CoefficientYear = c(1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
    2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
    2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
    2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
    2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
    1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 
    2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
    2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
    2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
    2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
    2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
    1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 
    2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
    2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
    2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
    2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
    2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 
    1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
    2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 
    2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
    2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
    2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L), DataYear = c(2009L, 
    2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
    2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
    2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
    2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
    2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
    2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
    2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 
    2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
    2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
    2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
    2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
    2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
    2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
    2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
    2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
    2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
    2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
    2018L, 2018L), Percent = c(19.80424276, 18.46883619, 17.68356676, 
    16.44767208, 15.19147958, 13.82855804, 12.48396228, 10.43429397, 
    8.100766173, 5.779730258, 2.166231372, 0, -3.285714286, -7.769953931, 
    -10.59166368, -13.14621037, -14.60640197, -14.65642282, -15.29803602, 
    -17.98803602, -20.69803602, 23.08995704, 21.75455048, 20.96928105, 
    19.73338637, 18.47719387, 17.11427232, 15.76967656, 13.72000825, 
    11.38648046, 9.065444544, 5.451945658, 3.285714286, 0, -4.484239645, 
    -7.305949392, -9.860496079, -11.32068769, -11.37070853, -12.01232173, 
    -14.70232173, -17.41232173, 27.57419669, 26.23879012, 25.45352069, 
    24.21762601, 22.96143351, 21.59851197, 20.25391621, 18.2042479, 
    15.8707201, 13.54968419, 9.936185303, 7.769953931, 4.484239645, 
    0, -2.821709747, -5.376256434, -6.836448043, -6.886468885, 
    -7.528082084, -10.21808208, -12.92808208, 30.39590643, 29.06049987, 
    28.27523044, 27.03933576, 25.78314326, 24.42022172, 23.07562596, 
    21.02595765, 18.69242985, 16.37139394, 12.75789505, 10.59166368, 
    7.305949392, 2.821709747, 0, -2.554546687, -4.014738296, 
    -4.064759138, -4.706372337, -7.396372337, -10.10637234, 32.95045312, 
    31.61504655, 30.82977713, 29.59388245, 28.33768995, 26.9747684, 
    25.63017264, 23.58050433, 21.24697654, 18.92594062, 15.31244174, 
    13.14621037, 9.860496079, 5.376256434, 2.554546687, 0, -1.460191609, 
    -1.510212451, -2.15182565, -4.84182565, -7.55182565, 34.41064473, 
    33.07523816, 32.28996873, 31.05407405, 29.79788156, 28.43496001, 
    27.09036425, 25.04069594, 22.70716815, 20.38613223, 16.77263335, 
    14.60640197, 11.32068769, 6.836448043, 4.014738296, 1.460191609, 
    0, -0.050020842, -0.691634041, -3.381634041, -6.091634041, 
    34.46066557, 33.12525901, 32.33998958, 31.1040949, 29.8479024, 
    28.48498085, 27.14038509, 25.09071678, 22.75718899, 20.43615307, 
    16.82265419, 14.65642282, 11.37070853, 6.886468885, 4.064759138, 
    1.510212451, 0.050020842, 0, -0.641613199, -3.331613199, 
    -6.041613199, 35.10227877, 33.7668722, 32.98160278, 31.7457081, 
    30.4895156, 29.12659405, 27.78199829, 25.73232998, 23.39880219, 
    21.07776627, 17.46426739, 15.29803602, 12.01232173, 7.528082084, 
    4.706372337, 2.15182565, 0.691634041, 0.641613199, 0, -2.69, 
    -5.4, 37.79227877, 36.4568722, 35.67160278, 34.4357081, 33.1795156, 
    31.81659405, 30.47199829, 28.42232998, 26.08880219, 23.76776627, 
    20.15426739, 17.98803602, 14.70232173, 10.21808208, 7.396372337, 
    4.84182565, 3.381634041, 3.331613199, 2.69, 0, -2.71, 40.50227877, 
    39.1668722, 38.38160278, 37.1457081, 35.8895156, 34.52659405, 
    33.18199829, 31.13232998, 28.79880219, 26.47776627, 22.86426739, 
    20.69803602, 17.41232173, 12.92808208, 10.10637234, 7.55182565, 
    6.091634041, 6.041613199, 5.4, 2.71, 0), Value = c(0.198042428, 
    0.184688362, 0.176835668, 0.164476721, 0.151914796, 0.13828558, 
    0.124839623, 0.10434294, 0.081007662, 0.057797303, 0.021662314, 
    0, -0.032857143, -0.077699539, -0.105916637, -0.131462104, 
    -0.14606402, -0.146564228, -0.15298036, -0.17988036, -0.20698036, 
    0.23089957, 0.217545505, 0.20969281, 0.197333864, 0.184771939, 
    0.171142723, 0.157696766, 0.137200083, 0.113864805, 0.090654445, 
    0.054519457, 0.032857143, 0, -0.044842396, -0.073059494, 
    -0.098604961, -0.113206877, -0.113707085, -0.120123217, -0.147023217, 
    -0.174123217, 0.275741967, 0.262387901, 0.254535207, 0.24217626, 
    0.229614335, 0.21598512, 0.202539162, 0.182042479, 0.158707201, 
    0.135496842, 0.099361853, 0.077699539, 0.044842396, 0, -0.028217097, 
    -0.053762564, -0.06836448, -0.068864689, -0.075280821, -0.102180821, 
    -0.129280821, 0.303959064, 0.290604999, 0.282752304, 0.270393358, 
    0.257831433, 0.244202217, 0.23075626, 0.210259576, 0.186924299, 
    0.163713939, 0.127578951, 0.105916637, 0.073059494, 0.028217097, 
    0, -0.025545467, -0.040147383, -0.040647591, -0.047063723, 
    -0.073963723, -0.101063723, 0.329504531, 0.316150466, 0.308297771, 
    0.295938824, 0.283376899, 0.269747684, 0.256301726, 0.235805043, 
    0.212469765, 0.189259406, 0.153124417, 0.131462104, 0.098604961, 
    0.053762564, 0.025545467, 0, -0.014601916, -0.015102125, 
    -0.021518257, -0.048418257, -0.075518257, 0.344106447, 0.330752382, 
    0.322899687, 0.310540741, 0.297978816, 0.2843496, 0.270903643, 
    0.250406959, 0.227071681, 0.203861322, 0.167726333, 0.14606402, 
    0.113206877, 0.06836448, 0.040147383, 0.014601916, 0, -0.000500208, 
    -0.00691634, -0.03381634, -0.06091634, 0.344606656, 0.33125259, 
    0.323399896, 0.311040949, 0.298479024, 0.284849809, 0.271403851, 
    0.250907168, 0.22757189, 0.204361531, 0.168226542, 0.146564228, 
    0.113707085, 0.068864689, 0.040647591, 0.015102125, 0.000500208, 
    0, -0.006416132, -0.033316132, -0.060416132, 0.351022788, 
    0.337668722, 0.329816028, 0.317457081, 0.304895156, 0.291265941, 
    0.277819983, 0.2573233, 0.233988022, 0.210777663, 0.174642674, 
    0.15298036, 0.120123217, 0.075280821, 0.047063723, 0.021518257, 
    0.00691634, 0.006416132, 0, -0.0269, -0.054, 0.377922788, 
    0.364568722, 0.356716028, 0.344357081, 0.331795156, 0.318165941, 
    0.304719983, 0.2842233, 0.260888022, 0.237677663, 0.201542674, 
    0.17988036, 0.147023217, 0.102180821, 0.073963723, 0.048418257, 
    0.03381634, 0.033316132, 0.0269, 0, -0.0271, 0.405022788, 
    0.391668722, 0.383816028, 0.371457081, 0.358895156, 0.345265941, 
    0.331819983, 0.3113233, 0.287988022, 0.264777663, 0.228642674, 
    0.20698036, 0.174123217, 0.129280821, 0.101063723, 0.075518257, 
    0.06091634, 0.060416132, 0.054, 0.0271, 0), Method = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "CPI"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -210L), class = "data.frame")
    Inflation



          iData <- structure(list(ID = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Indicator = c("Water consumption", "Water consumption", 
"Water consumption", "Water consumption", "Water consumption", 
"Water consumption", "Water consumption", "Water consumption", 
"Water consumption", "Water consumption", "Water consumption", 
"Water consumption"), IndicatorID = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), InputA = c(0.8, 0.864291561, 
0.756825327, 0.824653656, 0.852538526, 0.764414391, 0.751809875, 
0.747453768, 0.844790034, 0.720459608, 0.816295228, 0.858032971
), Input.A.Name = c("Water consumed", "Water consumed", "Water consumed", 
"Water consumed", "Water consumed", "Water consumed", "Water consumed", 
"Water consumed", "Water consumed", "Water consumed", "Water consumed", 
"Water consumed"), InputB = c(" NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA ", 
" NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA "
), Input.B.Name = c(" NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA ", 
" NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA ", " NA "), UnitCode = c("GBP", 
"GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", "GBP", 
"GBP", "GBP"), DataYear = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L), Country = c("ALL", 
"Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", 
"Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", 
"Australia"), ISO = c("ALL", "AFG", "ALB", "DZA", "ASM", "AND", 
"AGO", "ATG", "ARG", "ARM", "ABW", "AUS"), Division = c("One", 
"One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", "One", 
"One", "One"), Further.Details.1 = c("fd1a", "fd1a", "fd1a", 
"fd1a", "fd1a", "fd1a", "fd1a", "fd1a", "fd1a", "fd1a", "fd1a", 
"fd1a"), Further.details.2 = c("fd2a", "fd2a", "fd2a", "fd2a", 
"fd2a", "fd2a", "fd2a", "fd2a", "fd2a", "fd2a", "fd2a", "fd2a"
)), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")

  iData




Coeffb <- 1.98

CoeffbYear <- 2018

CoeffbCurrency <- 'GBP'

    Step1 <- iData %>% 
  ### filter for required indicator ID 

  filter(IndicatorID == 10) %>% 
  ##### Add column with step

  mutate(Step = 1) %>%
  ###### calculation

  mutate(iresult_step1 = InputA * Coeffb) %>%

  ##### Inflation TDB #######

  mutate(iresult_pos = iresult_step1 * (1 +  with(Inflation, Value[DataYear== DataYear & CoefficientYear== CoeffbYear &  Code==CoeffbCurrency])))
```

Ideally, if the DataYear for my InputA value in iData is 2018, and the coefficient year is 2018, then the subset function should return 0 and the result_step1 value will be multiplied by 1. Currently it doesn't seem to be pulling the DataYear from the iData correctly and I get an error message saying 'Warning message:
In iresult_step1 * (1 + with(Inflation, Value[DataYear == DataYear &  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length'. I'm not really sure on the best way to make sure it uses the correct DataYear, if I put it in manually then the formula runs, but is obviously incorrect for the data points from a different year.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Hopefully what I've written makes sense!

N.B my iData is much bigger, but cut down to the first 10 rows as it was too big.

Comment: Have you loaded some other packages than `dplyr` and  `tidyverse` (like `plyr`)? I just executed your code and got no error.

Comment: Hi, @iago thanks for taking the time to help! I have those three packages loaded and I'm still getting the error. My actual iData dataset is about 5000 rows, do you think this could be causing the problem?

Comment: Hi @iago I think I've worked out what's causing the problem, my iData isn't a multiple of the indicator file and that seems to be causing the error. I've edited the code above so that the iData is no longer a multiple, and the error appears. Do you have any idea how to get around this? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I meant you shouldn't have loaded the package `plyr` since R is taking the function `mutate` from that package. Either, you can specify `dplyr::mutate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Warning message says that you are performing an operation on vector with different length.

```
Step0 <- iData %>% 
+     filter(IndicatorID == 10) %>% ### filter for required indicator ID 
+     mutate(Step = 1) %>% ##### Add column with step
+     mutate(iresult_step1 = InputA * Coeffb)

with(Inflation, Value[DataYear== DataYear & CoefficientYear== CoeffbYear &  Code==CoeffbCurrency]) %>% length
#[1] 10
Step0$iresult_step1 %>% length> with(Inflation, Value[DataYear== DataYear & CoefficientYear== CoeffbYear &  Code==CoeffbCurrency]) %>% length
#[1] 12
```

Indeed, you are trying to multiply a vector of 10 by a vector of 12.

### EDIT

You are using 2 dataframes, therefore the best thing to do is to merge them using joins:

```
#table(dy=Inflation$DataYear, cy=Inflation$CoefficientYear, co=Inflation$Code)
Inflation2 = Inflation %>% filter(CoefficientYear== CoeffbYear &  Code==CoeffbCurrency)
#table(dy=Inflation2$DataYear, cy=Inflation2$CoefficientYear, co=Inflation2$Code)
Step1 <- iData %>% 
    left_join(Inflation2, by = c("DataYear")) %>% 
    filter(IndicatorID == 10) %>% ### filter for required indicator ID 
    mutate(Step = 1) %>% ##### Add column with step
    mutate(iresult_step1 = InputA * Coeffb) %>% ###### calculation
    mutate(iresult_pos = iresult_step1 * (1 +  Value))
```

With this code, the warning disapeared, and you don't need the `with` anymore (which is often a bad design when you use `dplyr`, `DataYear== DataYear` would always be `true`).

However, I guessed the key to join the dataframes by the names only so please check if this makes sense. The results are different so you were right not to ignore this warning :-)

Comment: Thank you that would be really helpful! I still get an output, but I'm concerned by the warning message incase anything has gone wrong and the results are incorrect

Comment: @MeganCritchley Please check my edit. It is possible that your results were incorrect. Let me know if this helped you. Best luck!

Comment: Hi @Dan Chaltiel that's great thanks! I actually just came up with a very similar solution but yours a little tidier than mine haha. Thanks for the help!